# After Effect: How do I achieve the smoke effect?

Tags: after-effects

I am trying to make the smoke after as seen in the picture attached. I have tried to search for the tutorials but there isn't any tutorial that teach me exactly the effect I wanted to create. [image]

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell from your question exactly what you're trying to do.  If you could link to a *video* of the effect you're trying to reproduce, or phrase your question more specifically, you will get more helpful information.

If you're looking for realistic smoke, fluid dynamics simulation isn't really something that After Effects can do on its own.  You'll need to get the physics right in another package, and probably render it elsewhere too, then maybe *composite* it in After Effects.  This is an extremely complicated topic, and there isn't one tutorial that covers it all.  But you might want to look into some other software like [this](http://www.creativebloq.com/audiovisual/simulating-fluids-81412590).

But if you just want to "fake" it, you can just use different layers of fractal noise attached to particles.  For this type of effect, search [videocopilot.net](http://www.videocopilot.net) for tutorials on  [Red Giant's Trapcode Particular](https://www.redgiant.com/products/trapcode-particular/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
This is the video of that showing the effect I wanted to create.

I have tried mimic this effect by using the fractal noise effect but it doesn't quite look the same. I just wonder if there is other way in making it.

 
https://youtu.be/VZ4xmgvf-iE?t=2m2s